# Package rar is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, rar

I've added multiverse repository as per similar questions.  I also confirmed on https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/rar that the package should be in that repository.

My version:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Sources:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

I've run apt update but I still get the error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install rar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package rar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'rar' has no installation candidate
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

In your `sources.list`, you have a lot of `ports.ubuntu.com` sources, which means that you probably have an ARM processor.

In https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/rar, you can see that it is only available for `amd64`, i.e. common 64-bit x86 processors (this is quite common for proprietary software, where the vendor does not provide a package for anything other than 64-bit x86 systems).

This package is not available for ARM, which is why you get this error message.

---

### How to use RAR on ARM?

According to [this](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-linux-arm.html) website, [this](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.peazip.PeaZip) flatpak package is available for ARM, and can unpack rar archives.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub io.github.peazip.PeaZip
```

Comment: That's it, I'm running on a pi which I forgot uses arm arch.  I literally looked at that availability and thought but I'm using amd64... no I'm not /facepalm

Comment: @EricSandvik 
I am glad that you are having such a good experience on your Pi that you subconsciously thought you are on a "regular" computer.

Comment: 7-Zip can also extract some .rar archives.